# Travis build failing, no module named scipy (using Miniconda)

Tags: python, scipy, travis-ci, miniconda

I have a package which has scipy as a dependency. I am already aware that installing scipy through `apt-get` gives us an outdated version of the package and that installing it through `pip` times out the Travis VM, so I decided to download and install Miniconda during my tests, like suggested in many other questions.

However, whenever I push to GitHub and Travis runs my unit tests, it fails to find the `scipy` package. The error message is simply `ImportError: No module named 'scipy'`.

Here is the content of my `.travis.yml` file. `python --version` points correctly "to Python 3.4.4 :: Continuum Analytics, Inc." and `conda list` shows that scipy 0.17.0 is installed. If anyone is interested, here is the [full log of my Travis build](https://travis-ci.org/douglasrizzo/catsim/builds/108962933).

```
language: python
python:
  # We don't actually use the Travis Python, but this keeps it organized.
  - "3.4"
install:
  - sudo apt-get update
  # We do this conditionally because it saves us some downloading if the
  # version is the same.
  - if [[ "$TRAVIS_PYTHON_VERSION" == "2.7" ]]; then
      wget https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -O miniconda.sh;
    else
      wget https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -O miniconda.sh;
    fi
  - bash miniconda.sh -b -p $HOME/miniconda
  - export PATH="$HOME/miniconda/bin:$PATH"
  - hash -r
  - conda config --set always_yes yes --set changeps1 no
  - conda update -q conda
  # Useful for debugging any issues with conda
  - conda info -a
  - conda create -q -n test-environment python=$TRAVIS_PYTHON_VERSION numpy scipy scikit-learn matplotlib
  - source activate test-environment
  - conda list
  - python --version
  - whereis python
  - python setup.py install
script: nosetests
```

Comment: travis uses virtualenv for python by default, what is the output of `which python`?

Comment: `/home/travis/miniconda/envs/test-environment/bin/python` after creating the other virtualenv with conda. [Here is the new build](https://travis-ci.org/douglasrizzo/catsim/builds/108981540).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your python doesn't correspond to the virtual environment seen in the travis log. At a guess, I'd say `nosetests` is using its own venv.

So look at `nosetests`: it may have a different, hardcoded shebang as first line (`head -n1 $(which nosetests)` may do), thus using a different python and different venv.

If the above is correct, the solution is probably to install your own version of nosetests. That should take priority (being earlier in your PATH).

Comment: That was exactly it. The shebang lines before and after I install `nose` through conda are different. Everything works right now. Thanks!

Comment: To add, but this is more guesswork: the default travis VM is probably set up with a standard set of utilities, and nosetests happens to be one of them. I guess the take home message is "always *explicitly* anything you need yourself". Or rather, that's been largely my motto for quite some time :-).

Comment: Indeed, nosetests is a default utility in a Python VM, as seen [here](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/python#Pre-installed-packages). And I have learned my lesson: from now on, make everything I'm going to use explicit.